# Kohana create user with role

Tags: php, kohana

```
    $user = ORM::factory('User');
    $user->username = 'test';
    $user->email = 'test@test.com';
    $user->password = 'test';
    $role = ORM::factory('Role')->where('name', '=', 'login')->find();
    $user->add('roles', $role);
    $user->save();
```

I get an error:

```
Column 'user_id' cannot be null
```

how can I fill the user_id, if I didn't even created the user yet?, can't find any explanation for this

Answer (score 0):

Your database table (which I'm assuming is called 'users') needs an auto incrementing id. If the user_id field is auto incrementing you won't have to populate the user_id field as it will do it for you. In phpMyAdmin there is a check box that says A_I in the structure tab when editing an attribute.

Comment: Is the error coming from the database API or from the framework your using? Because if it's coming from the API (mysqli or PDO) then it is not auto incrementing.

Comment: the thing is that first I need to save the user in order to get the newly created(and already auto incremented) ID, so I can set the role to this ID, but I think there is a way that this stuff works automatically, not manually like I do it now